# What PCL Profiles does Autofac 4 support?

Tags: autofac

We're using Autofac 3.5.2 in a PCL of ours (Profile259) and Nuget tells us that version 4.1 is available, but when we attempt to update it Nuget fails with the message:

"You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Has anyone been able to get Autofac 4.1 working in any PCL profile?

Thanks!
-Tom B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autofac 4 was released using a [`netstandard` target framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) which is part of the new .NET Core platform. The point of `netstandard` is to replace the myriad and slightly confusing PCL targets with something easier to figure out.

**Autofac 4 supports `netstandard1.1`.** [The documentation on the netstandard TFM ("target framework moniker") explains the compatibility of that.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) In a nutshell:

- .NET 4.5+ (`net45`)
- Mono / Xamarin platforms
- Universal Windows Platform 10 (`uap10.0`)
- Windows 8.0 (`win8.0`)
- Windows Phone 8.1 (`wpa8.1`)

It does *not* support Windows Phone Silverlight anymore (`wp8.0`) - that ended with `netstandard1.0`.

`netstandard1.1` is compatible with these PCL profiles (also per the docs):

- Profile7
- Profile32
- Profile44
- Profile111
- Profile151

It's not compatible with Profile259 - that's `netstandard1.0`. The incompatibility is the Windows Phone Silverlight target, which is deprecated and no longer supported in Autofac 4.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! It looks like it's not possible to use the netstandard1.1 with Xamarin Studio right now due to the combination of a bug in .NET Core (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10445) and the fact that XS uses Nuget 2, but good to know that we should at least theoretically be able to update to Autofac 4 at some point in the future!

Comment: On Profile111 it fails with "Could not install package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author." Not Autofac itself, but one of its dependencies.

Comment: Here is the issue with Profile111 and 44 described https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10445

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

Add a `project.json` to your project:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "4.2.0",
    // your other dependencies here
  },
  "frameworks": {
    ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111": {}
  },
  "supports": ""
}
```

Close and re-open the project (and possibly Xamarin Studio). I also added the Nuget v3 feed to Xamarin Studio (I just had version 2 listed), but I'm not sure if that helped. You can roughly follow [this blog post](https://oren.codes/2016/02/08/project-json-all-the-things/).